# REST, Spring with annotations, Jackson and handling of generic classes

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, jackson

I am trying to use Spring with Jackson to implement REST service using JSON as data interchange format. Now I have hit a road block with handling of generic classes in Jackson/Java. I am reading [JacksonDataBinding](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonDataBinding?highlight=%28%5CbCategoryJackson%5Cb%29) page but I do not understand how I could use the information to help me with the issue when using Spring annotations. Given a basic response class like this, how do I make it work properly with Jackson and Spring together?

```java
public class BasicResponseDto<ResponseDataType> { 
   private ResponseDataType data;
   // ...
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to do custom JSON responses, or just let Jackson handle it?  If you just want Jackson to handle it, then you should be able to add the `@ResponseBody` to your handler and simply return the object (or collection of objects), and Spring/Jackson will handle the rest.

Comment: @CodeChimp: We are using `@ResponseBody`. The issue is that we are getting 406 HTTP response the first time and only subsequent queries succeed.

Comment: Ah, see, that wasn't mentioned.  A 406 means that the request produces a response that is not in accordance with what the request headers say it can accept.  You need to start by verifying that the request says it can accept `application/json` and the response includes the `Content-Type` = `application/json`

Comment: @CodeChimp: We have that Content-Type header there.

Comment: Can you also post a simplified but working example - basically the full Controller method, including the mapping, and then how you're trying to consume it - perhaps via a `curl` command - that will definitely speed up diagnosing your issue. Cheers.